# Ideas on spatial puzzles for a city walk

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, puzzle-creation

**Background.**
With the relaxation of covid-related restrictions, there was a need for intelligent city walks. Walk here is a moving between city objects by a certain (deterministic/stochastic) route.

I am looking for ideas of puzzles in the city in which you need to use basic knowledge of mathematics.

As examples of puzzles  I can give:

- [The Konigsberg bridges problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg),
- Measuring the height of a building by the shadow ([Thales method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales_of_Miletus), described in the book by Jules Verne),
- A bottle search with a note using known coordinates (used in a TV show).

[Subway Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subway_Challenge)

**Question:** What are puzzles can be proposed using different points of view like stairs, flagpoles, fountains, parks, bridges, cross-roads, buildings, monuments, metro/underground stations?

Comment: Some simple ideas, not sure if they are any good: finding the shortest path to a target location, solving a maze, finding the mid-point between two buildings, counting the number of steps in a tall building (harder than it looks!).

Comment: Geocaching comes to mind. Not only do they involve geo-coordinates, but harder, lengthier ones also involve logical and other types of puzzles as clues to get the final coordinates.

Comment: @Earlien, thank you, could you share an example?

Comment: @Nick There are many online communities. Maybe this site will help answer some questions: https://www.geocaching.com/guide/